# Increase the throughput of kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am reading data from a CSV file and pushing that into 3 Kafka brokers using Java code.

But, I am getting only 5 message/sec as throughput, while my expectation is about 200 message/sec

I am using asynchronous mode for pushing the data

below is my producers.properties

```
buffer.memory: 100000000 
batch.size: "3276800"
linger.ms: "5" 
compression.type: lz4 
retries: default 
send.buffer.bytes: 10458760  
connections.max.idle.ms: 10000
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: batch.size is used to increase throughput, did you check whats the size of those 5 msgs?

Comment: its around 13mb ..

Comment: can you post your producer code? CSV parser code?

Comment: I am  reading the file using bufferreader ,splitiing on comma delimiter , storing each spllited value in an array and sending it to producercer code

Comment: But when I am running my code jar file 11 times at once  , I am getting 250 message/sec throughput .. Can anybody explain why ?

Answer (score 0):

Why write code to do this? Just use Kafka Connect (which is part of Apache Kafka) and https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir which includes support for CSV files. Chances are this is going to perform better, and it's easier to maintain, to deploy, etc.